# UIWebView won't play youtube videos

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Right now I'm baffled by this problem, and haven't been able to find anything useful on Stack Overflow.

I am working on an app with an in-app browser when a user clicks a link. Right now, it's just a full-size UIWebView in a UINavigationController. I am able to load webpages with the UIWebView just fine, but when there is a Youtube embed, I am not able to play the video.

I'm using this URL to test: http://kottke.org/13/10/the-grand-budapest-hotel

When I load the URL using the in-app browser in Twitterific, the video is playable. When I load it in my in-app browser, I get a black box with the red play button from Youtube, but when you tap the play button, it disappears and the video never loads.

```
_webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
[_webView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[_webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[self.view addSubview:_webView];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

Am I missing a setting on the UIWebView?

Comment: I don't see where you set the URL of the website to load?

Comment: Updated the code to include it. I had moved the loadRequest away from the init as one attempt to debug. The webpage loads fine either way, it just doesn't show the thumbnail for the youtube video or load when I try to play it.

Comment: Turned out Youtube was having issues at that specific time, and it resolved itself.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
NSString *html = [self getHTML:videoId];
[self loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];

- (NSString *) getHTML: (NSString *)videoID
{
    if (videoType == videoTypeYoutube)
    {
        NSString *youTubeVideoHTML = @"<html>\
        <body style=\"margin:0;\">\
        <iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@\" frameborder=\"0\">\
        </iframe>\
        </body>\
        </html>";
        NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:youTubeVideoHTML, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height, videoId];
        return html;
    }
}
```

Roughly that anyway (I've cut & pasted stuff out of a subclass I used).

Comment: That's great, but the problem isn't any custom HTML. It's an actual webpage that has the embedded video. My test case being: http://kottke.org/13/10/the-grand-budapest-hotel